# How to consolidate methods that are the same with the exception of object Types

Tags: c#

I have 7 methods that are the same with the exception of the Type of the object.

Here are two of them:

1)

```
public MyResult CreateMyResult(MyResult mi, MyVersion myv)
{
    MyVersionEntity myve = _db.MyVersionEntity.Where(r => r.Id == myv.Id).First();
    MyResultEntity mie = new MyResultEntity();
    myve.MyResultEntityAssoc.Add(mie);
    mie = _updateMyResultEntity(mi, mie);
    mi.Id = mie.Id;
    return mi;
}
```

2)

```
public MyIssue CreateMyIssue(MyIssue mi, MyVersion myv)
{
    MyVersionEntity myve = _db.MyVersionEntity.Where(r => r.Id == myv.Id).First();
    MyIssueEntity mie = new MyIssueEntity();
    myve.MyIssueEntityAssoc.Add(mie);
    mie = _updateMyIssueEntity(mi, mie);
    mi.Id = mie.Id;
    return mi;
}
```

Is there a way to consolidate all of them?

Thanks!

Comment: So `MyResultEntity` and `MyIssueEntity` share no common base type or interfaces despite being operated on in the same way?

Comment: How about creating a Delegate

Comment: @Eric Do you have control over the code of `MyIssue`, `MyResultEntity`, etc?  I.e. is rewriting them an option?

Comment: Ikh, yes, rewriting is an option. But, where to start. What am I missing to properly design the classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use generic that is

```
public T Create<T>(T mi, MyVersion myv)
{
    MyVersionEntity myve = _db.MyVersionEntity.Where(r => r.Id == myv.Id).First();
    Entity<T> mie = new Entity<T>();
    myve.EntityAssoc<T>.Add(mie);
    mie = _updateEntity<T>(mi, mie);
    mi.Id = mie.Id;
    return mi;
}
```

after call it like this

```
 Create<MyResult>(...)
 Create<MyIssue>(...)
```

Comment: You'd also need to add a generic parameter for `MyIssueEntity`/`MyResultEntity` type.  Also, note that the use of `MyVersionEntity.MyIssueEntityAssoc` or `.MyResultEntityAssoc` also varies between the functions.